# How to run kotlin code with root privilege?

Tags: android, kotlin, root

I'm using this library to get root access https://github.com/topjohnwu/libsu

I can run bash code with root privilege;

Initialization:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    companion object {
        init {
            //here goes static initializer code
            Shell.enableVerboseLogging = BuildConfig.DEBUG
            Shell.setDefaultBuilder(
                Shell.Builder.create()
                    .setFlags(FLAG_REDIRECT_STDERR)
                    .setFlags(FLAG_MOUNT_MASTER)
                    .setTimeout(10)
            )
        }
    }
//onCreate
}
```

Bash usage:

```kotlin
val srcDir = "data/data"
val result = Shell.cmd(" ls '${srcDir}'").exec() //This will list the root protected directory
```

But, I want to run **kotlin** code (*not bash*) with root privilege.

Eg:

```kotlin
val dirChilds = File(srcDir).list() //It seems only that shell has root access not the whole app.
```

Comment: Launch the app with root privileges.

Comment: @m0skit0 How do you do this on Android , where starting the app using the framework isn't actually running an executable file... ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper The device has to be rooted (which is also the case for the OP question btw). Use whatever su GUI app you have, there are plenty.

Comment: @m0skit0 That's not answering the question. You can gain root, but how would you start the app with root? I'm talking within code

Comment: @androiddeveloper You're right, I somehow misremembered this could be done. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Kotlin code (not bash) with root privilege, you can use the following generic class that wraps the root access in your code:

http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's just running the bash commands one after another. He wanted to use framework commands as if they run on root. I don't think such a thing is possible.